# Proof verification: Prove that $\langle x,y\rangle=0 \leftrightarrow \|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{E}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

Proof verification: Prove that $\langle x,y\rangle=0 \leftrightarrow \|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{E}^n$.

$(\Longrightarrow)$ Suppose that two vectors are orthogonal, i.e., $\langle x,y\rangle=0$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
\|x+y\|^2 &= (x_1+y_1)^2 + \cdots + (x_n+y_n)^2 \\
   &= x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 + y_1^2 + \cdots + y_n^2 + 2(x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_ny_n) \\
   &= \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + 2\langle x,y\rangle  \\
   &= \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2
\end{align*}
$(\Longleftarrow)$ Suppose that $\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2$. In general, $\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + 2\langle x,y\rangle$. By the supposition, it must be true that $\langle x,y\rangle=0$.

I am only skeptical about $(\Longleftarrow)$ part because it seems too simple to be a proof.

Comment: It's fine. It seems so simple since you started the other way. You can repeat the proof in the reverse order.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more instructive this aproach:
$\|x+y\|^2=\left \langle x+y,x+y \right \rangle=\left \langle x,x \right \rangle+2\left \langle x,y \right \rangle+\left \langle y,y \right \rangle=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\left \langle x,y \right \rangle$